# Clicking check boxes in android

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing list view with a 40 dynamic check boxes. Problem is that when i click 1 check box other few check boxes are also checked for example if i click single check box then it will also makes other few check boxes to be ticked. I am using onClickListener for this. One of my code snippet is given below:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        FilterViewHolder holder;
        if (row==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.filterlist_row, parent, false);
            holder = new FilterViewHolder();
            holder.filterCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.filter_checkbox);
            holder.filterCheckBox.setTypeface(fontFace);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            //holder = (View) row;
            holder = (FilterViewHolder) row.getTag();

            /* When a listview recycles views , it recycles its present state as well as listeners attached to it.
             * if the checkbox was checked and has a onCheckedChangeListener set, both will remain a part of 
             * recycled view based on position. So it is our responsibility to reset all states and remove
             *  previous listeners.
             *  The listener was removed as below:-
             */
            holder.filterCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        }

            holder.filterCheckBox.setText(areaList.get(position));
            holder.filterCheckBox.setFocusable(false);
            holder.filterCheckBox.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
            holder.filterCheckBox.setText(areaList.get(position));

            holder.filterCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (isChecked) {
                        //change state of concern item in 'positionArray' array to 'True'
                         positionArray.set(position, true);
                        //add the checked item in to area list which used to filter offers.
                        filterOffersByThisAreaList.add(areaList.get(position));

                    } else {
                       //change state of concern item in 'positionArray' array to 'True'
                         positionArray.set(position, true);
                        //remove the unchecked item in to area list which used to filter offers.
                        filterOffersByThisAreaList.remove(areaList.get(position));

                    }
                }
            });
        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always call setChecked before returning on getView and Uncheck/check manually the checkbox that is inside the returned item, it likes that you are reusing the convertView that is passed on the getView() method that you implement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `position` directly in `onCheckedChanged` for setting status of `CheckBox` you should use `setTag` and `getTag` method to get position of checked item:

```
...
holder.filterCheckBox.setTag(position);
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int checkPos=Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
  ....your code here...
}
```